# Responsive Design - Site Showing Differently on iPhone versus Smaller Browser

Tags: iphone, css, responsive-design

I've added some media queries to [my site here](http://www.towntarget.com/categories/), which show correctly when I minimize the browser's window to the smallest size. Though unfortunately, when I navigate to one of the internal pages, the original design shows on the iPhone. When testing it in my browser, the site works properly regardless of what page I'm on.

Note: To test, minimize your browser to the smallest width which will show the "mobile site" that they wanted.

I'm completely stumped here. Could someone please point me in the direction as to why the iPhone seems to be loading old CSS while the browser itself is loading the current CSS?

Thanks!

Comment: How does it look different than expected on your phone? For me the skinny desktop version looks the same as my iPhone. Maybe a caching issue?

Comment: It works fine on the homepage but loads the "desktop version" of the internal pages. I've even tried emulators online and it seems to do the same.

Comment: I don't see the viewport tag on the internal pages, just see it on the home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could someone please point me in the direction as to why the iPhone seems to be loading old CSS while the browser itself is loading the current CSS?

You probably answer your own question. This definitely seems like a caching issue because I see the same site on both my mobile and desktop browser.

Try clearing your mobile browser's cache. If you use Safari, go to *Settings > Safari > Clear cookies and data*. If you use Chrome, or any other 3rd party browser, you can usually clear local files under the in-app settings page.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you include a viewport meta tag like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: I thought this might be the issue but I've already added this in. - Thanks so much for trying to help though!